# Keyboard shortcut for "Connect to Server" in Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssms

Is there a keyboard shortcut for the "Connect to Server" modal window in Microsoft SQL Server Server Management Studio?

The modal window that is displayed when you first opened up SQL Server Management Studio from the Start Menu or shortcut.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

F8 (Object Explorer), Alt + F (File Menu), E (Connect Object Explorer)

Comment: The Change Connection shortcut didn't work, but this old Alt+... trick worked, thanks

Answer (score 20):

Another way is to create a shortcut. For instance I use: Ctrl+K,Ctrl+O for this purpose.

1. TOOLS > OPTIONS
2. ENVIRONMENT > KEYBOARD > KEYBOARD
3. Write in Show Commands containing: Query.ChangeConnection
4. Press shortcut keys (which is currently not used by any other action)

Comment: This worked great for my query window.  Wondering if there is a way to do this for the Object Explorer?  Still upvoted it.

Comment: Thanks. After some hit n trial, I figured out that you can assign another short cut key for this one.
1. Write in Show Commands containing: Query.ChangeConnection
Use global **Ctrl+O Ctrl+E** (object explorer)

2. Write in "Show Commands containing" box: File.ConnectObjectExplorer
Use **Ctrl+K Ctrl+O**

Now you can use same key sequence (Ctrl+K Ctrl+O) for both places :)

Comment: Edit: The shortcut Ctrl+O Ctrl+E was not a good idea (While opening the docs, it waits for other part of shortcut :(). Fix: Use any other shortcut key, no first part of which is currently used.

Comment: Came here looking for exactly this (the query window version). Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Open a query in SSMS.  In the menu bar, select Tools -> Options -> Keyboard (Under the Environment node)

[image: Screenshot]

Within the Press Shortcut Keys – Press the key you would like to assign to the shortcut to.  In my case I have used F2.  Within the commands box highlight Query.ChangeConnection and click on assign.  This will now open up the SQL Server connection window on pressing F2.

https://ashleybickerstaffe.wordpress.com/2016/05/04/change-sql-server-management-studio-ssms-connection-keyboard-shortcut/

Answer (score 1):

only for ssms 2012

One work around that I found is to customize the listing of options on 'Query' menu bar and move the 'Change Connection...' option to the top under 'Query|Connection'. Once that is done, the keyboard shortcut would be,

**'Alt' + 'Q', 'Right Arrow Key' then 'Enter key'.**

Btw, to customize 'Query' to move 'Change Connection...' to the top:

1. right click on 'Change Connection' icon
2. Select 'Customize...'
3. Select 'Commands' tab
4. Select 'Query|Connection' from the 'Menu Bar' drop down
5. Select 'Change Connection...' options in the 'Controls:' box and move it to the top.

Now, **'Alt' + 'Q', 'Right Arrow Key' then 'Enter key'.**  is ready to use. Without the customization, the shortcut would be **'Alt' + 'Q', 'Right Arrow Key', 'Up arrow key' then 'Enter key'.**

Btw, to connect to object explorer, **Alt + F, E** works.